# Why doesn't daisyUI's theme apply to @tailwindcss/typography?

Tags: tailwind-css, typography, daisyui, freshjs, tailwind-plugin

I'm using Fresh and want to apply [daisyUI typography theme](https://daisyui.com/docs/layout-and-typography/). Here is my code:

##### `deno.json`

```json
"imports": {
  "$fresh/": "https://deno.land/x/fresh@1.6.1/",
  "preact": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2",
  "preact/": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2/",
  "tailwindcss": "npm:tailwindcss@3.3.5",
  "typography": "npm:@tailwindcss/typography",
  "daisyui": "npm:daisyui@4.4.19",
  "$std/": "https://deno.land/std@0.212.0/",
  "$gfm": "https://deno.land/x/gfm@0.2.5/mod.ts",
  "deno.importMap": "./import_map.json"
},
```

##### `tailwind.config.ts`

```js
import { type Config } from "tailwindcss";
import typography from "typography" 
import daisyui from "daisyui";
export default {
  content: [
    "{routes,islands,components}/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
  ],
  // plugins: [typography],
  plugins: [typography, daisyui],
  daisyui: {
    themes: ["light", "dark", "lemonade", "autumn", "aqua", "nord" ],
    logs: false
  },
} satisfies Config
```

##### `static/styles.css`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

##### `routes/_app.tsx`

```js
import { type PageProps } from "$fresh/server.ts";
export default function App({ Component }: PageProps) {
  return (
    <html data-theme="lemonade" class="h-screen">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" />
      <Component />
    </html>
  );
}
```

##### `routes/index.tsx`

```js
export default function Test() {
  return <div class="prose" >
    <h1 id="h1">h1</h1>
    <h2 id="h2">h2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, quos esse similique magnam, eos libero ex optio perferendis temporibus inventore magni iure consequuntur itaque accusantium. Exercitationem, distinctio omnis? Delectus, quibusdam.</p>
    <code>console.log(code)</code>
  </div> 
}
```

The code renders fine, but the style is from the vanilla plugin, not daisyUI. Why is that?